# Load test using NPM module loadtest causes server to return HTTP code 400

Tags: node.js, load-testing

I'm trying to perform load test using [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest). I'm trying to send a JSON object in POST parameter. Following command is used:

```
loadtest 'http://localhost:3000/outbreak/'
-m POST -H Content-Type:application/json -T application/json -t 2 -c 10 --rps 10
-P '{"country": "us", "state": "ma"}'
```

The server code can accept the same POST body and work as expected when trying from outside `loadtest`. But when I send this command to server via `loadtest`, the same server returns HTTP status code `400`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, found the solution. The double quotes needs to be escaped!

Correct syntax:

```
loadtest 'http://localhost:3000/outbreak/'
-m POST -H Content-Type:application/json -T application/json -t 2 -c 10 --rps 10
-P '{\"country\": \"us\", \"state\": \"ma\"}'
```