# Load Test Post Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, load-testing

My json data in postman body look down. I send a message request, it return status 200 as a result.

```
{
    "device": {
        "ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 8093,
        "username": "",
        "password": ""
    },
    "subscriber": {
        "id": "abcdefgh"
    }
}
```

I want to loadtest in post request but "too many arguments error" ?(return status 404)

```
loadtest -P '{"device": {"ip": ""1.1.1.1"port": 8093,"username": "","password": ""},"subscriber": {"id": "abcdefgh"}}'  -n 1000 -c 100 -T

Too many arguments: [
'{"ip":',
'"1.1.1.1","port":',
'8093,"username":',
'"","password":',
'""},"subscriber":',
'{"id":',
`"abcdefgh"}}'`,
```

'"
]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After the error you should see the arguments you pass in. There should only be one. Can you show the full error message?

Comment: My requests are failing I guess it's reading the json data wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just a general tip: start with a low number of requests, concurrency and requests per second first before hitting high figures.

Try escaping the double-quotes as mentioned in [Load test using NPM module loadtest causes server to return HTTP code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65300996/load-test-using-npm-module-loadtest-causes-server-to-return-http-code-400)

```
loadtest -P '{\"device\": {\"ip\": \"159.146.11.203\",\"port\": 8093,\"username\": \"\",\"password\": \"\"},\"subscriber\": {\"id\": \"abcdefgh\"}}' -n 1000 -c 100 --rps 2000 -T 'application/json' 'http://localhost:5050/subscribe-mobile-device'
```